# drop-down menu with php function

Tags: php, function

I've already created my html form with a drop-list menu of 5 selections

I want a selected option from the drop-list to call php function that will echo a selected option to the screen

```
<label>Fruits</label>
<select name="Fruits">
<option value="Ap">Apple</option>
<option value="BN">Banana</option>
<option value="OR">Orange</option>
```

Comment: Can you explain little bit clear?

Answer (score 2):

For example, here is your html code

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <title>Static Dropdown List</title>
 <body bgcolor="pink">
 Employee List :
 <select>
  <option value="Select">Select</option>}
   <option value="Moyed">Moyed Ansari</option>
   <option value="Asad">Asadullah</option>
   <option value="Usman">Usman Ali</option>
 </select> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Now You will use the above table in the dropdown list using the following code.

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Drop Down List</title>
</head>
<BODY bgcolor ="pink">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>">
        Employee List :
        <select Emp Name='NEW'>
        <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
        <?
            mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db ("company");
            $select="company";
            if (isset ($select)&&$select!=""){
            $select=$_POST ['NEW'];
        }
        ?>
        <?
            $list=mysql_query("select * from employee order by emp_id asc");
        while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
            ?>
                <option value="<? echo $row_list['emp_id']; ?>"<? if($row_list['emp_id']==$select){ echo "selected"; } ?>>
                                     <?echo $row_list['emp_name'];?>
                </option>
            <?
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Select" />
    </form>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

php is on the server side
where as all the html is on the user side..
if you want to echo the selected option, then you have to send the selected option to the server side using Ajax Request or using some other technique like POST a form.

```
// using jquery you can get your selected value
  <script>
     var selected_value = $("#idOfTheSelectTag").val();
     // or you can also do
     var selected_value = $("#idOfTheSelectTag :selected").text();
     // now you can post it to the php page using AJAX where you can echo it
     $.post('page_name.php', {SELECTED_VALUE : selected_value}, function(data){
                         // on the server side in page_name.php file if you echo the value then it will be returned in the data object in the function
                  });
  </script>
```